# Has there been a study or documentary on the influence of Ani-song themes on Japan's music scene?

Tags: music, culture

As noted on [How are the themes and songs picked for a particular series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3744/how-are-the-themes-and-songs-picked-for-a-particular-series), some anime openings are created for their show; thus, the song and anime theme usually coincide and work together.

Since these songs are widely promoted in Japanese society (and consumed largely by young ones that regard them highly as they grow), I guess these themes heavily influence Japan's music scene too.

At least the influence of early video game music is easy to note. The wide spread of anisons has to have had an influence in musicians.

Sure, the trace of influence might start with the society itself as in Society/Home → Author Experience → Piece of Work → Anime+Anison, and then feeds back to Society.

### The background of the question

I think that there's a lot more of songs that talk about peers understanding (in love, hurting, etc) in Japan than in Western music. The motivation for this question is to prove or disprove, since I'm making the assumption that these anisons lyrics/themes have influenced current Japanese song writers.

I do believe that Japanese writers express the need of Japan's society to communicate their problems to others and to understand other people struggles.

But there has been any study or documentary talking about this?

Even a formal investigation about this theme bias I see in the lyrics of Japan's music bands works. And sure, this might be just my imagination, is really uncommon that theme on western songs?

---

An example of these kind of [differences between japanese music and western music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtPx6WdNM30) is noted by Marty Friedman (former Megadeath guitarist). But what he talks about is the music composition, not the topics on jpop/jrock lyrics.

Comment: I certainly agree with your premise that there exist marked thematic differences between Western and Japanese popular music. I would be surprised if the anime song industry was a major driver of that difference, though. My impression is that anime music constitutes a relatively small fraction of the Japanese popular music market.

Comment: Yeah maybe anisons are a small fraction of the industry, but I think they represent a significant portion of the music young japanese hear. Also, I think their lyrics are more exposed by how openings are shown in the shows. Since the people more exposed are growing up kids I suggest their themes have an influence on later works.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a documentary specifically on the subject you requested, purely because I do not think that one currently exists. I did, however, find a number of articles that conducted largely unofficial research on such a topic. In general, has anime music affected the Japanese music industry?

**Yes.**

How?

I think the most significant effect is the broader audience. Due to anime's rapidly growing international fanbase, and with more and more shows being dubbed in languages other than Japanese and English, the music of anime is being broadcast across the globe. Anime allows the artists of this music to take their songs to the international stage. I think the effect of this *globalization* if you will can be see across many different anime.

For example, consider the music artist *Linked Horizon*. Before 2013, Linked Horizon produced a number of smaller projects, including a song for a Nintendo 3DS game. However, it wasn't until 2013, when the band composed the opening to Attack on Titan, that they truly took off in popularity. Their song rocketed to the top of the leaderboards and was and is a fan favorite across the world. This would not have been possible without anime.

In addition, there are examples of people changing their whole music tastes and playlists due to their newly found interest in Japanese music from watching anime. You can read [here](https://m.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/45gknf/how_has_watching_anime_affected_your_taste_in/) about anime watchers in the US and their changing tastes in music.

It conclusion, the largest effect anime has had on the Japanese music industry is its internationalization. Anime has helped to significantly broaden the audience of Japanese music.

[Here's](https://www.quora.com/How-much-influence-anime-shows-have-in-promoting-Japanese-music-to-international-audience) a very good article about anime's affect on Japanese music.